# SQL QUERY for inserting a record into PHPMyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

What I am trying to achieve is a SQL query which will insert a new product in the `product` table which has an auto incremented `product_id` value. However, in the `customer` table there is also a column for `product_id` which is a foreign key referencing the `product_id` value in the `product` table. Now, I can insert a new product and a new customer, but I would like to know how to write a script that takes a query which I can use in a PHP script which will allow a customer insert a new product so that the keys will relate automatically, so one customer can be related to many products.

I have tried the references in the PHP manual.

```
$query = mysql_query (" INSERT INTO events
                        VALUES
                        (   '',
                            '$event_type',
                            '$title',
                            '$description',
                            '$date',
                            '$target',
                            '$add1',
                            '$add2',
                            '$ci‌​ty',
                            '$postcode',
                            '$country',
                            '$tick',
                            NULL
                        )"
);
```

For example I have got an events table for the above query and the `NULL` value at the end of the query is for the foreign key column (`user_id`) which is from the `user` table...

If I was a user inserting the event how would I add my `id` to the event?

Comment: Please realise that you're __not__ inserting anything into phpmyadmin; you're inserting into a MySQL database.... phpmyadmin is simply a client program that allows you to look at data in a MySQL database

Comment: for that you need first your html code create that according to your demand and make php code

Comment: It's always good to add a picture or atleast a visual representation of your table to help see better.

Comment: better to sketch ur table on a paper it will help you to make logic :)

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that you should think about your database-model. Is it right, that one customer has got one foreign key to a product? It conflicts that you say that one customer can be related to many products.

Anyway; your problem is, that you insert a product and the ID is automatically generated so you don't know about it, right? You have to write it, read it out right afterwards to make your next insertion. I would recommend a stored procedure to handle this, because your PHP-script should not communicate with your Database as much as this.

Comment: $query = mysql_query ("INSERT into events VALUES ('','$event_type','$title','$description','$date','$target','$add1','$add2','$city','$postcode','$country','$tick',NULL)");                                                                     


for example i have got an event table for the above query and the Null Value at the end of the query is for the foreign key column (user_id) which is from the user table.......if i was a user inserting the event how would I add my id (that i cant view) to the event ?    @individumm

Comment: I can't follow you - you talked about customers and products. What is this now?!

Comment: This is an example i have used so imagine events is the product and user_id is the customer_id  @Individumm

Comment: @GeraldGray - could you edit that code into your question? It'll be a lot easier to read.